# three.js birds using single element

Tags: css, canvas, html5-canvas, three.js, css-transitions

While surfing the Internet I found the excellent JavaScript 3D library [three.js](http://threejs.org/).
The provided examples are SUPERB... 
One of them is [the canvas geometry birds example](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_birds.html).

I would like to create similar canvas with one bird randomly flying over screen background, how can I achieve the same effect using exclusively CSS3 & HTML5 canvas (without JavaScript).
 Is it possible? If so, can you please provide me some good reference to get started?